# Facet API: grouping indexed values into several drop-down facets

Tags: theming, search

I have an indexed field which contains values in such a form:

CPU: Intel Core i5
CPU: Intel Core i7
...
Memory: 4 GB
Memory: 8 GB
...
Video card type: Integrated
Video card type: Nvidia
...

I would like to display these as several drop-down lists, e.g:

Title: CPU  with values: Intel Core i5, Intel Core i7, ...
Title: Memory with values: 4 GB, 8 GB, ...
Title: Video card type  with values: Integrated, Nvidia, ...

Any suggestions would be welcome on how to implement this.
Thank you very much in advance.

Best regards,
Laszlo

Comment: Can you clarify what the indexed field values are? Is this a string: "CPU: Intel Core i5 CPU: Intel Core i7 ... Memory: 4 GB Memory: 8 GB ... Video card type: Integrated Video card type: Nvidia ..."?

Comment: Hello, the indexed values are originally field collection field with multiple values. The field collection field has among others a property name and a property value subfield. As I did not know any better options concatenated those fields as strings for the index.

Comment: I created a custom index, in which I concatenated the property name and the property value, so I have "CPU: Core i5", "CPU: Core i7" etc, "Video card manufacturer: Nvidia", "Video card manufacturer: AMD" and so on, for each of the several properties. There are several types of products involved notebooks, printers, even drones, so I cannot group these into separate fields and use separate dictionaries.

Comment: Maybe the way to do this is to implement a special widget, in which property values are grouped into separate drop-down lists based on the property name at the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, I'd use a vocabulary for each of the facets ('dropdowns'). Add a term referenece field to your node for each of those as well. Then add these fields to your search index and add the facets for them.

E.g.,
Vocabulary:
CPU

Terms: 
Core i5
Core i7
...

Vocabulary:
Memory

Terms:
4 GB
8 GB
..

Comment: The property names and values change from node to node because they belong to a variety of products, e.g. notebooks, printers, accessories, etc. I used a field collection with multiple values for the different properties (subfields: name and value). I cannot use a dictionary for each of those, there are just too many of the properties and the values.